# How to extract parent text from an ajax return data?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html data being returned from the ajax request

```
        <div> Log information from the following sessions
        <span class="comments"> your comments </span>
        <div>
        <div>Section B log information
        <span class="comments"> section B comments </span>
        </div>
```

Here is my attempt to remove all comment classes from this return ajax request but not working and that the comments are not being removed.

```
    $.ajax{
             url: pathToFile,
             success: function(data)
             {
                var removeComments = $(data).remove(".comments");
               alert(removeComments).html());
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.remove()` this way -

```
 $.ajax {
     url: pathToFile,
     success: function (data) {
         var removeComments = $(data).find('.comments').remove();
         alert(removeComments.html());
     }
 }
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/UMVyQ/2/

Comment: this is again a conflict and you beat me by 24 sec

Comment: the alert is showing text of the removed data, is this right? I thought I would not see alert of the removed data. Bascially, I was hoping to get the text of the parent by removing comment classes

Answer (score 2):

First of all find `(".comment")` and then `remove()`

```
 var removeComments = $(data).find(".comments").remove().html();
 alert(removeComments));
```